# How do I get HAProxy to not change the request URL?

Tags: https, haproxy, redirection

I setting up HAProxy, task is very easy - redirection to two servers on port 8443. I did it. But I have one trouble when I write in browser address line my domain (xyz.domain.loc), it replace my domain to server name (srv01.domain.loc or srv02.domain.loc) from DNS to which it redirect. How disable it? I want that in my browser stayid address - xyz.domain.loc.

Config:

```
frontend http-in
  bind *:80
  redirect location https://test.domain.loc:443/ if { hdr(Host) -i 
test.domain.loc }
  redirect location https://test2.domain.loc:8443/ if { hdr(Host) -i test2.domain.loc }
  redirect location https://xyz.domain.loc:8443/ if { hdr(Host) -i xyz.domain.loc }
  default_backend myit
...
frontend https-8443
  bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/certs.pem
  use_backend test2 if { hdr_dom(Host) -i test2.domain.loc }
  default_backend xyz
...
backend xyz
  balance     roundrobin
  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  option tcplog
  server srv01 1.1.1.1:8443 ssl check verify none
  server srv02 1.1.2.1:8443 ssl check verify none
```

Comment: Your application most likely changes it, check its settings first.

Comment: Yes, Tomcat configured with this option on the servers!